# Fabric.js loadFromJSON width/height properties deserialization

Tags: fabricjs

I have a problem with Fabric.js.

When I'm trying to save fabric canvas like this:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(self.canvas.toJSON(['width', 'height']))
```

I get well serialized json with **height** and **width** properties.
But when I'm trying to deserialize it like that:

```
self.canvas.loadFromJSON(data, function () {
    self.canvas.renderAll();
});
```

All objects init fine except **height** and **width** properties.

I saw deserialization example: http://jsfiddle.net/fmgXt/3/

If I add to json **height** and **width** properties its ignores with deserialization.

But if I set them into code - it also works well. Am I missing something?

At http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#loadFromJSON I didn't find any mentions for loadFromJSON about includedPropertiesNames list or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution to get missing attributes at deserialization :

```
var object = JSON.parse(json); //use default json parser
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function(){
            canvas.width = object.width;
            canvas.height = object.height;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This one made no luck for me.

I was able to make it working by `setWidth` and `setHeight` methods:

```
var object = JSON.parse(json); 
    canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
        canvas.setWidth(object.width);
        canvas.setHeight(object.height);
        canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
    });
```